# How do I bypass the login screen for Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am working on project for class and we need to generate crystal reports. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and operating with Crystal Reports for SP15. I have created a report and placed a crystal viewer on a blank asp.net webform however when I run the webform it asks for a database login. Has anyone experienced this issue or can anyone help me please? Thank you!

**Here is the code for my webfrom page:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim MyReport As SqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As ReportDocument
    Dim ALMOST As SqlCommand
    Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim DT As DataSet

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim commandString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HouseSwappingConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(commandString)

            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from ListTable", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds)

                Dim HouseSwap As New ReportDocument
                HouseSwap.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"))
                HouseSwap.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))

                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = HouseSwap
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind()
                CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically set logon parameters for the report,so that it will not ask for logon parameters during runtime.
first initialize a connection parameter like

```
Dim ConInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
```

now define the connection parameters for coninfo

```
        ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = ServerIP ' change with server name
        ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = DBname ' change with database name
        ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa"
        ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = DBPassword ' change with your password
```

now for all tables in the crystal report datasource set logon info as this

```
 For intCounter As Integer = 0 To HouseSwap .Database.Tables.Count - 1
            HouseSwap .Database.Tables(intCounter).ApplyLogOnInfo(ConInfo)
 Next
```

set this before setting the datasource for the report.hope it helps.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm relatively new to ASP.net so can you please explain where exactly I would find my server name, database name and password? I may be confused in what I'm entering.

Comment: look in the connection string.